# How to convert onClick to hover in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers map in my project,I'm displaying list of items on map.Whenever user clicks on item(feature) then item description will be popup instead of onClick,I want to convert to hover.To do this where I need to modify ?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you need to modify as you have not provided your code.  However below is a snippet taken from the OpenLayers example found [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/highlight-feature.html).

```
        var report = function(e) {
            OpenLayers.Console.log(e.type, e.feature.id);
        };

        var highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectors, {
            hover: true,
            highlightOnly: true,
            renderIntent: "temporary",
            eventListeners: {
                beforefeaturehighlighted: report,
                featurehighlighted: report,
                featureunhighlighted: report
            }
        });
```

so i would hazard a guess that you will need to simply add the line `hover: true` to your SelectFeature config, to fully select you could remove the line `highlightOnly: true` or change it to false. Also your report function would have your code for displaying a popup.

again, not sure this is what you need to do, if you post your code it will be easier to help.

Olly

Comment: Its working fine,how can I convert popup to link,means when hover's it as to popup some item information if user clicks on item,it as redirect to the feature(item) full description page,any idea?

Comment: i think you can add any HTML into the popup, so i'd just add a link into the text within the popup.  you'd probably be better of asking this in a new question with the code you currently have..